High CPU usage when idle
I would like to get an answer for this question: Why when no actions are being performed, my python program takes 14% of CPU, but when actions inside the loop are performed (toggle) it is only at 4%? (what I use is os, keyboard, pyautogui, time and Image from PIL)
So the problem is that it takes more CPU when it didn't perform any actions except checking for keyaboard press, than when doing all the presses and image findings.
I tryed searching this answer online, but my search was unsuccessful.
toggle = False
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(TOGGLE_KEY):
        toggle = not toggle
        if toggle:
            print('Dialogue Skipping ON.')
        else:
            print('Dialogue Skipping OFF.')
            time.sleep(1)

    if toggle:
        pyautogui.click(*DIALOGUE_SKIP_POSITION)
        pyautogui.press('space')

        try:
            dialogue = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
                dialogue_image, confidence=CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, region=SEARCH_REGION)
            if dialogue:
                pyautogui.click(dialogue)
        except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
            pass


We can’t help you without some code and more information. It looks like you might have a while loop somewhere that is not taking a rest.

Do you revert toggle after a click? Otherwise you'll do the if toggle logic every iteration, even tho you pressed the key minutes ago.

This is an endless loop with no delay. Why wouldn't it eat as much CPU as it could get? When you want to be efficient, you should use blocking calls that don't return until an event you care about happens, rather than checking state over and over and over.

"Why when no actions are being performed, my python program takes 14% of CPU" Because when there's no action it's a while True: pass so it loops as fast as it can with no waiting or anything. You need to use something like keyboard.wait so your program is only invoked when a key (ideally your hotkey) is pressed, then it goes back to sleeping when there's no activity

Applications that use a specific desktop shortcut don't spinwait looking for keystrokes, they register a shortcut with the OS or they install a keyboard hook. This way the OS calls them when something interesting happens

Based on the comments from Charles Dufffy and Masklinn, I resolved it using:
keyboard.wait(TOGGLE_KEY)

